# Using lex / creating scanner?

Tags: compiler-construction, lex, lexical-analysis

Recently, I have been studying compiler theory about lexical analysis.
As I understood there some ways for constructing the lexical scanner, like :

- Using Lex/Flex for generating the scanner automatically.
- Build your own one. In examples, I have encountered the switch case model using the read-ahead technique (simulating the DFA, NFA).

My question is which one of them is more suitable for implementing a basic programming language (consists variables, conditions, loop)?
How they should be used in practise? Is it possible to use them both?

Comment: A lexical scanner only divides the source into tokens; it won't help you parse the tokens into structures like loops and conditionals. If you want to build real software, use (f)lex; rolling your own lexical scanner is a lot more work, is a lot easier to maintain, requires a lot more debugging, and unlikely to be faster.

Comment: You can use either one, but it doesn't make sense to use both. Obviously the reason tools like lex/flex exist is that manually writing and maintaining a scanner can be quite cumbersome and time-consuming - especially if you are evolving the programming language as well as the lexer/parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lex is useful for *simple* languages, but is not used in those with *complicated* syntax (for example, flex/lex do not use a scanner written in lex to process lex input).  Occasionally someone asks how to manage multiple syntax scanners (long ago, I helped someone on a program with multiple lex *and* yacc files — using sed, because this was before there were flex/bison with the options to help with renaming).

For a practical demonstration, [vi-like-emacs](http://invisible-island.net/vile/filters.html) uses lex/flex for *most* of the syntax highlighting modules.  Not all.  Perl and ruby turn out to be too complex to bother with in lex/flex, due to the way they embed regular expressions with little clue.  On the other hand, it has a workable (but large) scanner for lex/lex — written in lex.  For the sake of example, I added a copy of that to [vile's FAQ](http://invisible-island.net/vile/vile.faq.html#clone_syntax) (see [result](http://invisible-island.net/vile/lex-filt.l.html)).

One can make a list of things like that, but as a rule, the reason for using lex or not is the complexity of the syntax.  Also, managing error recovery is (according to some) a reason for the choice.

Comment: Scanners have nothing to do with syntax.

Comment: We can argue about terminology, but you have apparently too much spare time.